# What format applies to the Hive LazySimpleSerDe

Tags: csv, hive, hive-serde, hiveddl, lazysimpleserde

What exactly is the format for Hive `LazySimpleSerDe`?
A format like ParquetHiveSerDe tells me that Hive will read the HDFS files in parquet format.

But what is `LazySimpleSerDe`? Why not call it something explicit like `CommaSepHiveSerDe` or `TabSepHiveSerDe`, given LazySimpleSerDe is for delimited files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LasySimpleSerde` - fast and simple SerDe, it does not recognize quoted values, **though it can work with different delimiters, not only commas**, default is TAB (`\t`). You can specify `STORED AS TEXTFILE` in table DDL and `LasySimpleSerDe` will be used. For quoted values use [OpenCSVSerDe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001812/2700344), it is not as fast as `LasySimpleSerDe` but works correctly with quoted values.

LasySimpleSerDe is simple for the sake of performance, also it creates Objects in a lazy way, to provide better performance, this is why it is preferable when possible (for text files).

See this example with pipe-delimited (`|`) file format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095278/2700344

`show create table` command for such table prints serde class as `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe`, STORED AS TEXTFILE is a [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44454578/2700344).